# C# Switch-case string end with

Tags: c#, string, switch-statement, case

Is there any way to make a case condition in a switch statement where you say if a string end with something?

```
switch (Pac.Sku)
{
    case "A":
        pacVM.Sucursal = "Managua";
        break;
    case "B":
        pacVM.Sucursal = "Masaya";
        break;
    case "C":
        pacVM.Sucursal = "Leon";
        break;
    default:
        pacVM.Sucursal = "N/A";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .StartsWith in a Switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952528/using-startswith-in-a-switch-statement)

Comment: use if else or regex with switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not a way!
You can only use the if-else

```
if (Pac.Sku.EndsWith("A") )
{
    pacVM.Sucursal= "Managua";
}
else if (Pac.Sku.EndsWith("B"))
{
    pacVM.Sucursal= "Masaya";
}
else if (Pac.Sku.EndsWith("C"))
{
    pacVM.Sucursal= "Leon";
}
else
{
    pacVM.Sucursal= "N/A";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the last character of the string, and switch over the result:

```
switch (Pac.Sku.Last())
{
    case 'A':
        pacVM.Sucursal = "Managua";
        break;

    case 'B':
        pacVM.Sucursal = "Masaya";
        break;

    case 'C':
        pacVM.Sucursal = "Leon";
        break;

    default:
        pacVM.Sucursal = "N/A";
        break;
}
```

If the string could be `null` or empty use something like this function instead of [`Last()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775(v=vs.110).aspx). This function returns `null` if the string is `null`, `null` if the string is empty, and the last character of the string if it is not `null` or empty:

```
char? GetLast(string s)
{
    return s?.Length > 0 ? s.Last() : (char?)null;
}
```

Switch:

```
switch(GetLast(Pac.Sku))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can 
use  [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) feature of C# 7.0 to achieve this. Here is a very basic example:

```
var t = "blah";

switch (t)
{
    case var a when t.EndsWith("bl"):
        Console.WriteLine("I'm not here");
        break;

    case var b when t.EndsWith("ah"):
        Console.WriteLine("I'm here");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Unused `a` and `b` indicate a gross misuse of pattern matching feature. You ended up with an `if` statement disguised as a `switch`.

Comment: Don't think I particularly agree with this. You may have several conditions which fall into standard `switch` `case` statements and if you have a couple which have additional string manipulation I would rather prefer to have unused variables. It is certainly not a gross misuse in my humble opinion. In case there is only one such case, I can name the variable as `_`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Can you explain why this is a "gross misuse"?

Comment: @Enigmativity Because it uses an advanced language facility to express something that is adequately expressed by a more basic language facility, and introduces unused elements in the process.

Comment: Hi @dasblinkenlight, don't think pattern matching is an advance feature, it is surely new. The examples from Microsoft docs show that it indents to solve the issue of ugly/ multiple `if` `else`. Even in their examples, there are unused variables. As far as usage is concerned, I think it is more of a personal preference. I would personally prefer it over multiple `if`, `else` like many others and I'm sure there are others who won't. I consider these unused variables more like what we get with `TryParse` methods, you have to define them even when you don't need them.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I've always thought that a `switch` statement was just another form of `if`/`then`/`else`. I don't this this usage is much different.

Answer (score 2):

You can get creative with a `Func<string, string>[]` like this:

```
Func<string, string>[] cases = new Func<string, string>[]
{
    x => x.EndsWith("A") ? "Managua" : null,
    x => x.EndsWith("B") ? "Masaya" : null,
    x => x.EndsWith("C") ? "Leon" : null,
    x => "N/A",
};

Func<string, string> @switch = cases.Aggregate((x, y) => z => x(z) ?? y(z));

string result = @switch(Pac.Sku);
```

I have tested this with sample input that matches each of the cases and it works just fine.

One significant advantage with this approach is that you can build the `Func<string, string>[]` at run-time. Nice for creating configurable solutions.

You're also not limited to just using `EndsWith` - any condition can be used that suits the purpose.